# Operating on multiindex dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe `head()` looks like this:

```
                                         followers  following
experience   userid date                                     
Intermediate 0      2010-01-02 05:28:38      84330       1331
                    2010-01-02 18:46:36      84330       1331
                    2010-01-02 18:47:22      84330       1331
                    2010-01-02 18:50:12      84330       1331
                    2010-01-02 23:08:55      84330       1331
```

Where I have more rows.  For each userid, I'd like to subtract the first `followers` value (e.g., in example above, subtract 84330 from all dates in `userid=0`).  Is there some `apply()` command that will do this?

Comment: What do you mean by subtract? You mean remove the rows or subtract `84330` from a datetime which doesn't make sense to me

Comment: @EdChum: I mean subtract `84330` from the followers. Meaning for the rows shown above, make those `followers` 0.  However future rows may have more, so their value will be their current value minus `84330`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

find the first row for each userid:

```
cut = df.groupby('userid').first()
```

Then merge it back to the original table:

```
cut.columns = cut.columns.map(lambda x: str(x) + '_a')
df2 = df.merge(cut, left_on=['userid'], right_index=True, how='left')
```

Then remove these rows that match the first rows value

```
new = df2[df2['followers'] != df2['followers']][['userid','date','followers']]
```

Comment: This is close to what I want to do.  Please see my comment to EdChum above

Comment: You can replace the last line with:
df2["diff"] = df2["followers"] - df2["followers_a"]
Which will add a new column with the subtract between both values